# Can't install Slic3r on 16.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation, tar

I am trying to install Slic3r 1.2.9 stable. It downloads as a .tar.gz. It extracts fine but when switch to the Slic3r directory and I go to run the ./configure it says "command not found". There is a closed thread dealing with this topic none of the answers worked. I started trying this on 14.04 then upgraded to 16.04 hoping that might help. Nothing has so far.

Comment: There is nothing to compile in this case. Just use the binaries directly.

Answer (score 2):

Just use apt

```
sudo apt install slic3r
```

Comment: **IMPORTANT** i had huge problem with over extrusion on Slic3r 1.2.9. My suggestion is to install 1.3.0 (still development) and not available over aptitude. With same calibration and settings version 1.2.9 produced failed print and 1.3.0 was just fine.